# Random Data From Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

I'm using the Random Partitioner, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do the equivalent of a range scan to get a batch of random rows.  I assume that the rows are rather randomly placed on disk across the cluster?

In other words, given a row key in a random partition, is there a way to get X number of neighbors to that row as a random sample of data?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this by requesting an open-ended slice with a limit.

Using cassandra-cli, with a columnFamily of 'Test', you can do commands such as:

```
list Test['key':] limit 10;
```

Note that `['key':]` and `[:'key']` return the same results.